# Add an image to PDF via Google forms and Docs

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, google-forms

After following a tutorial to auto email a PDF on google forms submission which I have working I can not get images to show at all and it only puts the url file id instead

Basic premise > user submits form > script runs on submission > collects data from Google sheet > uses Google doc template copying and replacing {pic} place holders > converting doc to pdf and emailing > delete copy of doc

This is the part of the code I am trying to use to add the image to the doc template

```
//body.replaceText("{pic}", "");
// Convert image to blob
    //var myimage  = info['pic'][0];
    //var fileID = myimage.match(/[\w\_\-]{25,}/).toString();
    //var blob   = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID).getBlob();
    //body.insertImage(2, blob);
```

but it come back with Exception: DNS error: http://1J3uvrPAB3t9CjcQA5-ACWqKETlPwrkW9
at onFormSubmit(Code:27:26)
which is to be expected because it's not the complete url only the id

this is my form https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1gjCS1u0NLabT9SFdDs82mpH00JGj6UQwQ1ui69nX25k/edit?usp=sharing

This is the doc https://docs.google.com/document/d/17dwNK_reblefALIul6bmdFuuLjIltwuzjAUPqdHTUbc/edit?usp=sharing

this is the sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RgpO0-HRSNdzLXbCnAqMyrASuydgE9r8KmXacZP7CVc/edit?usp=sharing

I convert the sheet to remove the url link so it's just text but still nothing

This is the complete script in forms

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  //open the template document by ID
  //you can find the ID in the link of the document
  var templateDoc = DriveApp.getFileById('17dwNK_reblefALIul6bmdFuuLjIltwuzjAUPqdHTUbc');
  //create a copy of the template, we don't wanna mess up the template doc
  var newTempFile = templateDoc.makeCopy();
  
  //open the new template document for editing
  var openDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newTempFile.getId());
  var body = openDoc.getBody();

  // image
  
  //get the responses triggered by On Form Submit
  var items = e.response.getItemResponses();
  
  //find the text in the template doc and replace it with the Form response
  //items[0].getResponse() is the first response in the Form
  //and it is the "Name"
  Utilities.sleep(10000);
  //You can add as much as you have and change them in the Template Doc like this
  //body.replaceText('{pic}', items[0].getResponse());
  //body.replaceText('{choice}', items[3].getResponse());
  //and so on...
//Gets image url from sheets and adds image to doc
  body.replaceText("{pic}", "");
// Convert image to blob
    var myimage  = info['pic'][0];
    var fileID = myimage.match(/[\w\_\-]{25,}/).toString();
    var blob   = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID).getBlob();
    body.insertImage(2, blob);
  
  //Save and Close the open document
  openDoc.saveAndClose();
  
  var theBlob = newTempFile.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf');
  //The name of the file is going to be the first and second question from the form
  //change to your preference

  var d = new Date();
  var curr_date = d.getDate();
  var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
  var curr_year = d.getFullYear();

  var theDate = curr_date + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_year;

  var nameFile = items[0].getResponse() + ' - ' + theDate + '.pdf';

  //send an email with the PDF
  //If you don't want to send the PDF in the mail just delete everything
  //from here -------
  var email = items[1].getResponse();
  var subject = 'Test  ' +  theDate;
  var body = 'Hello, <br/>Please see attached PDF file.';
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
    htmlBody: body,
    attachments: [{
      fileName: nameFile,
      content: theBlob.getBytes(),
      mimeType: "application/pdf"
      }]
   });
   //to here ------

  // save the PDF file in your Drive
  
  var savePDF = DriveApp.createFile (theBlob);

  //if you want to save the file in a specific folder use this code
  //get the ID from the folder link
  //var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('14nUc----------0lUb');
  //var savePDF = folder.createFile (theBlob);

  savePDF.setName(nameFile);
  
  //delete the temp file
  DriveApp.getFileById(newTempFile.getId()).setTrashed(true);
}
```

Cheers in advance for any help given

Comment: I’m having trouble following your intention. A couple questions come up for me: 1) why are you getting an **_expected_** error? 2) what is the smallest amount of code you can show us that deals just with the issue at hand? Also, from the title it seems like you want to insert an image into a PDF, but everything else makes it look like you’re trying to insert the PDF into another Doc. Please take a few steps back and cut down your code to the bare minimum—for yourself and us. Get rid of all the comments of what it should be and let us focus on what it is.

Comment: Hi Zach, the image will be inserted into a doc file first then converted to PDF and emailed. The small code is the part that deals with retrieving the image url and adding it in to the 'pic' placeholder in the doc template, this is the info I followed https://howtogapps.com/google-form-to-pdf-save-to-drive-and-or-send-it-in-email/#comment-1312 to get the PDF from a forms response

Comment: 1) because the url is not complete, it should be https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vwqlTsUDro1JZ8AS-iAAIegUMJZvkFLk not http://1vwqlTsUDro1JZ8AS-iAAIegUMJZvkFLk so for sure it will fail

Comment: Hi, Darren. I still see so much in this post that does not relate to the issue at hand, which I believe is, “I cannot insert an image into a Google Doc.” You know that Doc will become a PDF, and then that PDF will get emailed… but here and now the issue is Google Doc and an image. Have you proven to yourself that you can simply insert an image into a Google Doc? I still don’t know what your actual problem is, and there’s so much code I cannot say what’s relevant. I recommend editing your post removing all the other context; get rid of anything that isn’t the actual problem/error.

Comment: I also recommend re-tagging this post and removing PDF ‘cause as far as I can tell, it’s not a PDF problem (at least not yet). Maybe I’m wrong about all this, but I think if you give your problem and this post some more thought and really define and boil down what the problem is you’ll get better help.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the images to be added to the PDF but I was able to add them to the email in the body which was a pretty good option for what I needed.

```
   function onFormSubmit1(e) {
   //insertImage ();

  //open the template document by ID
 //you can find the ID in the link of the document
 var templateDoc = DriveApp.getFileById('Google doc ID');
 //create a copy of the template, we don't wanna mess up the template doc
 var newTempFile = templateDoc.makeCopy();

 //open the new template document for editing
 var openDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newTempFile.getId());
  var body = openDoc.getBody();

 // image

 //get the responses triggered by On Form Submit
 var items = e.response.getItemResponses();

 //find the text in the template doc and replace it with the Form response
 //items[0].getResponse() is the first response in the Form
 //and it is the "Name"
 body.replaceText('{text}', items[0].getResponse());  
 body.replaceText('{text2}', items[14].getResponse());
 body.replaceText('{text3}', items[1].getResponse());
 body.replaceText('{text4}', items[2].getResponse());
 body.replaceText('{text5}', items[3].getResponse());
 body.replaceText('{text6}', items[4].getResponse());
 body.replaceText('{text7}', items[5].getResponse());
 body.replaceText('{text8}', items[6].getResponse());
 body.replaceText('{text9}', items[7].getResponse());
 body.replaceText('{text10}', items[8].getResponse());
 body.replaceText('{text11}', items[9].getResponse());
 //body.replaceText('{text13}', items[10].getResponse());
 body.replaceText('{text13}', items[13].getResponse());
 Utilities.sleep(1000);
 //You can add as much as you have and change them in the Template Doc like 
  this
  openDoc.saveAndClose();
  var theBlob = newTempFile.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf');
  //The name of the file is going to be the first and second question from 
  the form
  //change to your preference

  var d = new Date();
  var curr_date = d.getDate();
  var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
  var curr_year = d.getFullYear();

  var theDate = curr_date + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_year;

  var nameFile = items[0].getResponse() + ' - ' + items[14].getResponse() + 
  ' - ' + theDate + '.pdf';

  //send an email with the PDF
  //If you don't want to send the PDF in the mail just delete everything
  //from here -------
  //just add as many email addresses as you want
  var email = 'email@here.com, email@here.com' ;
  var subject = 'YOUR TEXT HERE  ' +  theDate;
  var body = 'Hello, <br/>Please see attached PDF file.';
  var picture1 = DriveApp.getFileById(items[10].getResponse());
  var picture2 = DriveApp.getFileById(items[11].getResponse());
  var picture3 = DriveApp.getFileById(items[12].getResponse());
  var inlineImages = {};
    inlineImages[picture1.getId()] = picture1.getBlob();
    inlineImages[picture2.getId()] = picture2.getBlob();
    inlineImages[picture3.getId()] = picture3.getBlob();
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
  htmlBody:'Hello <br/> <br/> MORE TEXT HERE <br/> <br/>Please see attached  
 PDF file.' + "" + theDate + '<br/> <br/> <b/r>' + 'Please see pictures 
below <br> <br> <br>' + 'Picture of:<br><img src="cid:' + picture1.getId() 
 + '" /><br>' +
 'Picture of:<br><img src="cid:' + picture2.getId() + '" />' + 'Picture of: 
 <br><img src="cid:' + picture3.getId() + '" />',
    inlineImages: inlineImages, 
    attachments:[
    //picture.getBlob(),
    {
    fileName: nameFile,
    content: theBlob.getBytes(),
    mimeType: "application/pdf"
    
  }]
    });
  
    //to here ------

    // save the PDF file in your Drive

    var savePDF = DriveApp.createFile (theBlob);

    //if you want to save the file in a specific folder use this code
    //get the ID from the folder link
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('FOLDER TO SAVE PDF IF REQUIRED');
    var savePDF = folder.createFile (theBlob);

    savePDF.setName(nameFile);

    //delete the temp file
    DriveApp.getFileById(newTempFile.getId()).setTrashed(true);
 
   }
```